# Stack Exchange home page "Top Network Sites" section layout is broken

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com

There is layout issue presently on https://stackexchange.com/ home page, in the "Top Network Sites" sidebar.

You can see it in this picture:

> [image]

OS : **UBUNBTU 12.04 LTS** ,
BROWSER : **Mozilla FireFox 32.0.3**  **>>> UPDATED to 33.0**

Comment: Might be browser extension/userscript/custom stylesheet you installed at some point. Try disabling those and see if it helps.

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest Firefox version, this might solve the problem.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Updated, still the same issue

Comment: I had Firefox 32 and upgraded to 33 now. No repro with either. Please go to `about:addons`, and see if there is anything you installed recently that might cause such thing. If you don't mind, post screenshot or list of your addons and maybe other will be able to identify the culprit.

Comment: (need all three tabs: Plugins, Extensions, and Appearance as each might contain something that can mess with the page design and break things)